# Should I use different team and bundle identifier in adding new swift extension?

Tags: swift, bundle-identifier, watch-notification

I want to add new target (watchOS-> Notification Service Extension) and it asks for team, bundle identifier and so on. By the way, this project was developed by a different team and I was asked to add new feature on this project. Do I need to use the same team and bundle identifier so that it will not cause errors or is it okay to use new team and bundle identifier? I'm new in swift programming so please be patient with me guys.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Swift whatsoever, but with application distribution, code signing etc.

I would very, very strongly recommend that you use the same build team. There should be documentation how to choose the bundle identifier. And everything can be changed later, so no reason to worry.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll consider it. @gnasher729